# How to recycle item from pool which is previously generated

Tags: java, android, generics, andengine, sprite

I am developing a game using andengine in which i am using Generic Pool for differents sprites
now my game is similar to fruit ninja in which fruit pop up on screen but after sometime or 15min later game become slow as i am using

```
  TargetPool tPool;
  tPool = new TargetsPool(apple,watermelon,lemon,mango,tomato);
  target=tPool.onAllocatePoolItem();
  tPool.onHandleRecycleItem(target);

 public class TargetsPool extends GenericPool<Sprite> {

private ITextureRegion mTextureRegion, mTextureRegion1,mTextureRegion2, mTextureRegion3,mTextureRegion4;

public TargetsPool(ITextureRegion pTextureRegion1,ITextureRegion pTextureRegion2,ITextureRegion pTextureRegion3,ITextureRegion pTextureRegion4,ITextureRegion pTextureRegion5) {
    if (pTextureRegion1 == null&&pTextureRegion2 == null) {

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The texture region must not be NULL");
    }
    mTextureRegion = pTextureRegion1;
    mTextureRegion1 = pTextureRegion2;
    mTextureRegion2 = pTextureRegion3;
    mTextureRegion3 = pTextureRegion4;
    mTextureRegion4 = pTextureRegion5;

}

@Override
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int a =r.nextInt(5);
    //Log.e(Integer.toString(a),"a" );
    Sprite sprite;
    VertexBufferObjectManager getvertex = null;

    switch(a){
        case 0:
            sprite =new Sprite(0, 0, mTextureRegion,getvertex);
        break;
        case 1:
            sprite =new Sprite(0, 0, mTextureRegion1,getvertex);
            break;
        case 2:
            sprite =new Sprite(0, 0, mTextureRegion2,getvertex);
            break;
        case 3:
            sprite =new Sprite(0, 0, mTextureRegion3,getvertex);
            break;
        case 4:
            sprite =new Sprite(0, 0, mTextureRegion4,getvertex);
            break;
            default:sprite =new Sprite(0, 0, mTextureRegion,getvertex);
    }


    return sprite;
}

protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Sprite target) {
    target.clearEntityModifiers();
    target.clearUpdateHandlers();
    target.setVisible(false);
    target.detachSelf();
    target.reset();

}

 }
```

I want to know how to recycle target items again from pool as if i generate new target everytime game becomes slow

Comment: Why not just store the `new Sprite()`s instead of always creating them? Create them only once when they're not already available. Then the onAllocatePoolItem() could simply return the stored sprites. Is that what you want? _PS (another tip): Think about rewriting as `public TargetsPool(ITextureRegion... pTextureRegion)` as this allows any number of `ITextureRegion` objects to be passed in as an array._

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you access items from the `GenericPool`. Don't call `onAllocatePoolItem()` or `onHandleRecycleItem` yourself... You call `obtainPoolIem()` and `recyclePoolItem()` respectively to make use of the pool features. You should read the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/util/pool/GenericPool.java?r=081b452a22a79e04865e6ef72a60d1ceb3731482).